# No such schema 'org.gnome.shell.clock' error

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, clock

The command that I am trying to run is:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.clock show-date true`

but then I get the message saying `No such schema 'org.gnome.shell.clock' error`

I don't know why this is? I know I properly installed `gnome`, even when I type in `gnone-shell --version` I get `GNOME Shell 3.18.5`, and so I am not sure why I keep getting this error message?

I have done `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`, but then it says `gnome-shell is already the newest version (3.18.5-0ubuntu0.2)`, and so I don't think I have installed it incorrectly?

Comment: That `dconf` key has been removed/replaced in a previous version so the error is normal. Edit your title (and your post) and explain what are you trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That setting has been moved to `org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date` in GNOME 3.6. So to get the same effect in newer versions use this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date true
```

Comment: Is there a way to add the 2017 to the date?